# Как продолжить работу при ответе  Удалённый сервер возвратил ошибку (404)

Tags: веб-программирование, .net, c#

Csharp WinForm Net 4.5

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (404) Не найден.

При парсинге страниц иногда попадаються страницы которые не возвращают ответ, типо Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (404) Не найден. Требуеться выполнить чтото вроде такого

```
if (response == null)
{
  сохранить страницу в блек лист
  и начать процес заново
}
```

Это моё представление, но подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно, я почемуто не могу сделать это внутри класса?

Answer (score 1):

Оберните в `try ... catch`:

```
try
{
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
   HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
   if (errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
   {
      // Обрабатываем 404
   }
}
```